# Boost async_accept causes an 'access violation' - error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

```
Server::Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,std::string ip,short port,std::shared_ptr<ConnectionFactory> factory)
    : acceptor_(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(ip.data()), port)){

        m_factory = factory;
        start_accept();

        std::cout<<"Socket accepting connections..."<<std::endl;
}

void Server::start_accept(){
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::shared_ptr<Connection> conn = m_factory->create(io_service);

    acceptor_.async_accept(conn->socket(),
        boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this,conn,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}


void Server::handle_accept(std::shared_ptr<Connection> conn,const boost::system::error_code& error){

    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout<<"on connected"<<std::endl;
        conn->OnConnected();
        start_accept();
    }
  }
```

When I run the project I get following error:

`Access violation reading location 0xfeeeff02.`

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Please cut your code down to the *minimum* required to provoke the problem.

Comment: Not really -- I can't take the code you posted and compile it to test/debug it, since it's not complete. Post the *complete, minimal* code necessary to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Your `io_service` is going out of scope in `start_accept()`, that is not good and likely not what you intend.

change this

```
Server::Server( ... ) {
        m_factory = factory;
        start_accept();

        std::cout<<"Socket accepting connections..."<<std::endl;
}

void Server::start_accept() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
                        ^^^^^^^^^
    std::shared_ptr<Connection> conn = m_factory->create(io_service);

    acceptor_.async_accept(conn->socket(),
        boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this,conn,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}
```

to this

```
Server::Server( ... ) {   
        m_factory = factory;
        start_accept( io_service );
                      ^^^^^^^^^

        std::cout<<"Socket accepting connections..."<<std::endl;
}

void Server::start_accept( const boost::asio::io_service& io_service ){
    std::shared_ptr<Connection> conn = m_factory->create(io_service);

    acceptor_.async_accept(conn->socket(),
        boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this,conn,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}
```

Though, as your comments have suggested, you really should post a self-contained example of the problem. The above suggestion is my best guess.